# How do I convert boost::spirit::qi::lexeme's attribute to std::string?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

Consider:

```
struct s {
  AttrType f(const std::string &);
};
```

...and a rule `r` with an attribute `AttrType`:

```
template <typename Signature> using rule_t =
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator,
                          Signature,
                          boost::spirit::qi::standard::space_type>;

rule_t<AttrType()> r;

r = lexeme[alnum >> +(alnum | char_('.') | char_('_'))][
      _val = boost::phoenix::bind(&s::f, s_inst, _1)
    ];
```

When compiling this (with clang), I get this error message:

```
boost/phoenix/bind/detail/preprocessed/member_function_ptr_10.hpp:28:72: error: no viable conversion from
      'boost::fusion::vector2<char, std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> > >' to 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>'
                return (BOOST_PROTO_GET_POINTER(class_type, obj)->*fp)(a0);
                                                                       ^~
```

It's my impression that the problem is the type of the placeholder variable, `_1`.  Is there a concise way to convert `lexeme`'s attribute to `std::string` for this purpose?

If I interject an additional rule with an attribute type of `std::string`, it compiles:

```
rule_t<std::string()> r_str;

r = r_str[boost::phoenix::bind(&s::f, s_inst, _1)];
r_str = lexeme[alnum >> +(alnum | char_('.') | char_('_'))];
```

...but this seems a bit awkward.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `qi::as_string[]` (which will *coerce* the attribute into a string if a suitable automatic transformation exists).

Alternatively you can use `qi::raw[]` which exposes the source-iterator range. This will automatically transform into `std::string` attributes. The good thing here is that the input can be reflected unaltered (e.g. `qi::raw[ qi::int_ >> ';' >> qi::double_ ]` will work

In your case you can probably use `as_string[]`. But you can also fix the argument to take a `std::vector<char> const&`

---

Finally you *could* use `attr_cast<>` to achieve exactly the same effect as with the separate `qi::rule<>` (but without using the separate rule :)) but I don't recommend it for efficiency and because older versions of boost had bugs in this facility.

Comment: `as_string` seems to be precisely what I want. Thanks!